# jQuery: find all elements with <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, findelement

I'm looking to a way to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery) solution to all of the fields which have `<input type="number">`.

So far I've only seen the way to find element by ID using jQuery and then attach an input filter.
However, what I'm trying to achieve is to add such filter to **all** elements with the "numeric" type.

**Example:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="number">
    </div>                              
</body>
</html>
```

**JS Function:**

```
// Restricts input for the set of matched elements to the given inputFilter function.
(function($) {
  $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      } else {
        this.value = "";
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

**Application of the modifier to a particular element**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) { // I need to find ALL elements with input type = number here instead of just myTextBox
    return /^\d*$/.test(value);    // Allow digits only, using a RegExp
  });
});
```

**Update:**
I tried the following:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      } else {
        this.value = "";
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

if($('input[type="number"]').length > 0){
$('input[type="number"]').each(function(index, element){ console.log(element); // Successfully logs the element!
element.inputFilter(function(value) { // I need to find ALL elements with input type = number here instead of just myTextBox
    return /^\d*$/.test(value);    // Allow digits only, using a RegExp
  });

})
}
```

Getting the error:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an attribute selector:

```
$('input[type="number"]')...
```

Process the result als usual but beware that `inputFilter` is registered as a jQuery extension and is not defined on DOM elements:

```
// Iterate over the matched elements. 'element' values are DOM elements and thus oblivious to jquery. For this reason you cannot call `inputFilter` on them.
$('input[type="number"]').each( function(index, element){ 
    console.log(element); // Successfully logs the element!
}

// Untested code (jQuery should handle the overhead of iterating over the elements.)
$('input[type="number"]').inputFilter(
   function(value) { // I need to find ALL elements with input type = number here instead of just myTextBox
      return /^\d*$/.test(value);    // Allow digits only, using a RegExp
   }
);
```

Comment: Ok, that looks familiar to what I've tried, what would be the resulting type of that expression?

Comment: A collection of matched elements - the same as in using the id selector. In the latter case the collection has length of 1, but a collection it is, which you can easily check by trying to apply a DOM API method on it (which produces an error).

Comment: How can I apply the "inputFilter" function to all of those elements? Could you please add it to your example?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:
`(index):1319 Uncaught TypeError: element.inputFilter is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> ((index):1319)
    at Function.each (jquery-2.1.3.js:374)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.3.js:139)
    at (index):1318`
However, the code correctly identifies all of the number fields.

Comment: I've updated my question with the new approach and an image of the error. Still I don't understand why I can't apply the newly created function to the input box.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! Your code works perfectly in the JSFiddle, although it doesn't work in the iOS WebView. I suspect, some other JS hooks in the app might interfere with the code, for some reason, the value is always empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('input[type="number"]').length > 0){
    //do something like as $('input[type="number"]').each(function(index, element){ console.log(element); })
}
```

Comment: jQuery objects are tolerant of selectors matching no elements so the `if` is not necessary

Comment: Everything is ok :D If not have **if**, i think console will show warning.

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't.